# Jquery to capture value and pass the value to a hidden field

Tags: jquery

I wrote a script that  changes text based on user selection, which is working fine.
I am not sure how using Jquery to capture the user selected selection and pass the value below to the hidden field ie replace the value="100" with the user selected value  example value="trade"? -thanks

JQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('#trade').click(function() {
            $('#form').attr("class","trade");    //trade selected
            $('#trade').addClass("current");
            $('.lblMadlib112').text("some text1");// adds some text to this field           

         });

$('#football').click(function() {
            $('#formr').attr("class","football");//football    
            $('#football').addClass("current");
                       $('.lblMadlib112').text("some text here");// adds some text to this field      



         });

});
```

.NET stuff

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnThemeId" runat="server" Value="100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give that control a class, like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnThemeId" CssClass="hdnThemeId" runat="server" Value="100" />
```

Then select it that way and use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value, like this:

```
$('#trade').click(function() {
  $('#form').attr("class","trade");
  $('#trade').addClass("current");
  $('.lblMadlib112').text("some text1");
  $('.hdnThemeId').val("some value");
});
```

Comment: Thanks . I wanted to replace the value="100" with teh user selected value for example trade.

Comment: @user244394 -is `#trade` an input or...?

Comment: trade is one of the values that user clicks. i want to capture and change the value="100" with the "trade" value or value of "football", depending what the user clicked. so that the value becomes value="trade" or value="football"

Comment: @user244394 - ah in that case use the code above, just replace `$('.hdnThemeId').val("some value");` with `$('.hdnThemeId').val("trade");`

Answer (score 0):

like

```
<span id='football' rel='football_value'>football</span>
```

and

```
$('#football').click(function() {
            $('#formr').attr("class","football");//football    
            $('#football').addClass("current");
            $('.lblMadlib112').text("some text here");// adds some text to this field 
            $('#hdnThemeId').val($(this).attr('rel'));     



         });

});
```

Comment: Thanks...I forgot to add i want to change the value="100" with the user selected value. - thnaks

Comment: right. so the #football field has a rel attribute that holds some value. you update the hidden field with theat value which jQuery access with $(this).attr('rel')

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#hdnThemeId').val($('#trade').val());
```

Comment: This is ASP.Net, that ID isn't guaranteed to stay `hdnThemeId`.

Comment: The latest version of .NET allows for controlling how IDs are generated: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx